# Why Driver driven Node based material switch dose not reflect in 3D view?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have used mix node to switch between materials in node editor and have used driver to control the switch. It renders properly i mean with correct material when switched but does not show in 3D viewport.

[image]

**Switched**

[image]

**Why it dose not refresh in 3D viewport?**

Comment: Probably a bug...

Comment: Dependency graph bug, if I recall.

Comment: @someonewithpc, NoviceInDisguise, Polosson, zeffii, SixthOfFour.  
I am new to blender and can not understand whether something is bug or mistake. Thanks for clarification that its bug. 
Now the question remains if some has found some hack to refresh the scene so that the right texture loads. It's very crucial for animation